# How to set match_parent and wrap_content depending on condition in xml?

Tags: android, height

I need to set the layout_height of TextView depending on some condition. I have tried with importing LayoutParams but it did not work. Any ideas?

```
android:layout_height="condition ? wrap_content : match_parent"
```

**I need to do it in xml not with code**

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can do it with a custom [Binding Adapter](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/binding-adapters).

> Create Binding Adapter as below

```
public class DataBindingAdapter {
    @BindingAdapter("android:layout_width")
    public static void setWidth(View view, boolean isMatchParent) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.width = isMatchParent ? MATCH_PARENT : WRAP_CONTENT;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);
    }
}
```

Then use this attribute in your `View`.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="@{item.isMatchParent, default = wrap_content}"
    ...
/>
```

**Note:**

`default = wrap_content` is important, because width and height should be specified when view is created, whether binding happens after bit time of view rendering.

## Explaination

#### Why it is not possible without `BindingAdapter`.

Because Android does not provide `View.setWidth()`, size can be set by class `LayoutParams`, so you have to use `LayoutParams`. You can not use `LayoutParams` in xml because again here is no `View.setWidth()` method.

**That's why below syntax gives error**

> Cannot find the setter for attribute 'android:layout_width' with parameter type int

```
<data>

    <import type="android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams"/>

<data>

android:layout_width="@{item.matchParent ? LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT : LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT}"
```

#### Setting Visibility by xml works, because there is `View.setVisibility()` method available

**Below syntax works**

```
<data>
    <import type="android.view.View"/>
    <variable
        name="sale"
        type="java.lang.Boolean"/>
</data>

<FrameLayout android:visibility="@{sale ? View.GONE : View.VISIBLE}"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should change it via LayoutParams:

```
    if(condition){
    LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = MATCH_PARENT;
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);}
else{
LayoutParams params = (LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = WRAP_CONTENT;
    textView.setLayoutParams(params);}
```

Comment: Would it make any difference?

Answer (score 0):

> I think you use ConstraintLayouts that provides all solutions

Comment: This should be a comment

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a == b ) {

view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

} 
else 
{
view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
}
```

Comment: Is the condition is based on the dimension size or something ? I'm not sure why you needed to do it in the xml when you will be able to do the same programatically without much hassle

Answer (score -1):

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">  

    <data>  

        <variable  
            name="user"  
            type="<package name>.UserModel" />  

        <import type="android.view.View"/>  
    </data>  

    <RelativeLayout  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="match_parent">  

        <TextView  
             android:layout_width="@{user.email.trim().length()>10 ? wrap_content : match_parent}""  
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
             android:text="@{user.email}"  />  

    </RelativeLayout>  
</layout>
```

Here try this I got this solution from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/code/2901/if-then-statement-with-databinding-in-android.aspx)

Comment: the solution is for visibility. the problem is that is not working for wrap_content, match_parent